# Storing geopolitical data in mysql

Tags: mysql, database-design, street-address, zipcode

My application has users and properties, both of which can have addresses. This application is also going to be heavily analytical, and we will need to be able to grab all addresses that belong to a specific city, zip, county, or state.

Storing Countries, States, and Counties is easy, because a state belongs to exactly 1 country, and a county belongs to exactly 1 state.

However, when storing zip codes and cities, the problem becomes a bit more complex. A state can have multiple zip codes, and a zip code can belong to multiple states. A zip codes and cities can also belong to multiple states/counties. Heck, some cities and zips might not even belong to any counties like Washington, DC.

Is there an established database model I can use to ensure that I account for all edge cases, while at the same time allowing querying by each type?

Comment: There is, but it's a secret,

Comment: Lol thanks for the helpful comment

Comment: This is just a [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) problem and there's entire libraries of books written on the subject. No database model can account for *all* edge cases because, by definition, there's always an edge to what your schema can accommodate. You just set the edge far enough out that whatever issues you do have aren't a problem for your users.

Comment: Remember, "county" is not a universal concept, not even inside the US. Some states divide things up differently. Some places in the US aren't even states per-se, they're territories or districts or possessions or *not even a place at all*, as is the case with military addresses.

Comment: And LA has parishes and AK has boroughs and San Francisco is both a city and county and ...

Comment: I found a database with about 10 million point names.  It has a country_code, a commalist of alternative country codes, and 4 columns for "administrative units".

Comment: Do you have a list of "all addresses" and what they are in?  That would be billions of rows.  Or will you depend on latitude & longitude?

Answer (score 0):

> However, when storing zip codes and cities, the problem becomes a bit
>   more complex.

Firstly you need to create Countries,cities,States and zip_codes.

It's obvious there is M:M relationship between States and Zip_codes entities, so you will need to create a new table and let us call it States_Zip_codes which comprises  two foreign keys State_id FK and  Zip_Id as FK.

> A zip codes and cities can also belong to multiple states/counties.

In this case the relationship is one to many, so Zip_code_id (the primary key of Zip_codes table) is a FK in States table and so on.

I don't understand the nature of relation it's many to many or one to many

> some cities and zips might not even belong to any counties like
>   Washington, DC

So in city_name field (property) it would be null

Hope that helps.
.